# Automatic selection in drop-down menu

Tags: php

I have a drop-down menu to select the city I want the weather forecast to be show. However, when the php runs the 1st time and the 1st city is shown, it doesn't show the weather values, just blank fields. Surprisingly, it works well after I click in 2nd or 3rd city and then go back and click on 1st city.

I have checked why this happens and it seems that $city (that is needed to run the rest of the script) is not available when the php runs the first time and that explains the blank forecast.

This can be checked here [1]: http://www.meteocaldas.com/previsao3.php

Can anyone please give me any idea on how to solve this? (I am a begginer!)
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$arr = ["Caldas da Rainha", "Lisboa", "Peniche" ];
if( $_POST['city']){
$city=$_POST['city'];
}
?>

<form name="f" id="a" method="post" action="">
<select id="city" name="city" onchange="this.form.submit()" >                      

<?php
foreach ($arr as $a){
if($a == $city){
    echo "<option value='{$a}' selected >$a</option>";
}else{
    echo "<option value='{$a}' >$a</option>";
}
}
?>

</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `$city` variable is init with value only when your form is submitted, you must set a default value for your `$city` variable `$city = $arr[0]` before `if` statement

Comment: Thank you so much Catcon! Now when php runs, the first city already shows the forecast and that is perfect! However, now when I try to switch to 2nd or 3rd city, it returns to the first city. I am using $city to get the forecasts for each city and now it seems that $city only takes the first city name and doesn't change. Can you be so kind to give me a little help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you put `$city = $arr[0]` BEFORE the `if($_POST['city'])` statement?

Comment: I did this <?php  foreach ($arr as $a){ $city = $arr[0]; if($a == $city){ ... but now I put it as you mentioned and the result seems to be the same. It can be cheked here [1]: http://www.meteocaldas.com/previsao2.php

Comment: So you reset the `$city`'s value to `$arr[0]` no matter what the user selects. Move the assignment to before the `if($_POST['city'])` will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much Catcon. Problem solved and you were right of course :-) Fault was mine cause I hadn't deleted the previous assignment! Thank you so much once again and everything working like a charm!